# Enable Shadow Catcher Pass in View Layer with Python

Tags: python, scripting, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

I am writing a script for compositing, which requires that the Render Layers node has the Shadow Catcher output (see image below).

[image]

This can be done with the GUI by going into the View Layer and toggling on the Shadow Catcher Pass, as such:
[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do this using script. In fact, the [`ViewLayer`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html) class doesn't seem to have a property for this, but does have it for other passes (e.g. `use_pass_combined`).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parameter is actually contained in the [bpy.types.ViewLayer.cycles](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html?highlight=cyclesrenderlayersettings#bpy.types.ViewLayer.cycles) property.

If you enable python tooltips and hover over the field you'll see this.

[image]

Notice the second line which states `CyclesRenderLayerSettings.use_pass_shadow_catcher`. A [quick search](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=CyclesRenderLayerSettings&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) in the docs gives us the only place where this class is used.

The docs don't explain what's inside it but you can always try `print(dir(bpy.context.view_layer.cycles))` to get an insight into what you can call exactly from this object.

`['__annotations__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__module__', '__weakref__', 'bl_rna', 'denoising_store_passes', 'name', 'pass_debug_sample_count', 'register', 'rna_type', 'unregister', 'use_denoising', 'use_pass_shadow_catcher', 'use_pass_volume_direct', 'use_pass_volume_indirect']`

This gives us :

```
import bpy

bpy.context.view_layer.cycles.use_pass_shadow_catcher = True
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the detailed answer.